# how to import javax in java?

Tags: java, jsp, import

I need an object of javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter in my JAVA program. I have to import javax, but I do not know how to do it.

I use ant for compiling my project and no IDE, just commandline.

Should I download a package or something and put it in my project? Or there is another way?

Comment: I wonder what you're gonna try to accomplish with a JspWriter in a Java SE application?

Comment: I am developing an advance logsystem, which should have the feature to show logs in web-page,and for that I need a ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IDE would ease thing considerable. Ant intergrates with Eclipse and helps to ease management of imports.

For the commandline; download the appropriate jar, add it to the classpath using -Djava.ext.dirs=

I presume that you can take it from here!

Comment: any link for downloading the package?

Comment: Tomcat has a jar that contains the required classes.

Answer (score 1):

To import `javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter` you place an import statement at the top of your file, after the package declaration, but before the class declaration. The import statement would look like:

```
import  javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter;
```

This tells the compiler to interpret uses of `JspWriter` as `javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter`

For example:

```
package somepackage;

import  javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter;

public class AClass {
    //Class contents here
}
```

Comment: I did that, but the problem is that ant errors, and says it does not know the javax.servlet.jsp package

Answer (score 0):

> I need an object of javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter in my JAVA program. I
>   have to import javax

No you don't, you have to import javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter. So do that. If it doesn't compile, adjust your classpath or your IDE project settings to include the appropriate JAR file.